# 'Package Configuration' screen but I unable to press <ok>

Tags: updates, release-juno

[image: This screen appeared but I can not press <ok>]

I trying to do `sudo apt-get upgrade` and the screen says **Package Configuration** and there is an <kbd>Ok</kbd> in the bottom but i can not press it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Please press <kbd>Tab</kbd> from your keyboard, keep pressing until <kbd>Ok</kbd> gets focus.